# For the polynomial

Tags: algebra-precalculus

For the polynomial, -2 is a zero. $h(x)= x^3+8x^2+14x+4$. Express $h(x)$ as a product of linear factors.

Can someone please explain and help me solve?

Comment: Apply Ruffini's rule http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruffini%27s_rule

Comment: $$h(x)=(x+2)(x^2+6x+2)\Rightarrow\dots$$

Answer (score 1):

Apply the Euclidean division of $x^3+8x^2+14x+4$ and $x+2$ and you will get:
$$x^3+8x^2+14x+4=(x+2) \cdot (x^2+6x+2)$$
Then find the roots of $x^2+6x+2=0$

Comment: The division/factorization in not needed - see my answer.

Comment: @BillDubuque: How is Vieta more efficient? As far as I can tell it only gives $x^2+6x+2=0$ in a different fashion.

Comment: @IlikeSerena For me it is. I can solve it the way I mentioned in $< 10$ seconds of  *mental* arithmetic, which, for me, is quicker and easier than mechanically applying the polynomial division algorithm. I doubt many people can do polynomial division mentally. Of course, in some sense, it is an optimization of the division algorithm. But one that often comes in handy.

Comment: @BillDubuque: Heh. I can do the division algorithm in about the same time (in this particular case), without even writing anything down except the answer. I suspect it's a matter of preference.

Comment: @IlikeSerena I meant $10$ seconds for the entire problem. I highly doubt that anyone can match that by *rotely* applying the division algorithm. Probably you are applying some optimization(s), which doesn't count as rote (mechanical) application of the algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\ $ You can infer the sum and product of the other 2 roots because you know the sum and product of all 3 roots (from the coefficients, by Vieta).

Answer (score 1):

Since its a cubic equation, you are looking at $$(x+A).(x+B).(x+C)=x^3+8x^2+14x+4$$

Obviously, you have to multiply and work hard towards solving this and getting the answer.

Alternatively, what you can do is represent the same thing as

$$x^3+8x^2+12x+2x+4=0$$

Or, $$x(x^2+8x+12)+2(x+2)$$
Or, $$x(x+6)(x+2)+2(x+2)$$
Or, $$(x+2)(x(x+6)+2)$$
Or, $$(x+2)(x^2+6x+2)$$

Solving the second equation for x will give $$x= -3 +\sqrt{7}$$

and $$x=-3-\sqrt{7}$$

and $$x=-2$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $a$ is a root of the polynomial $f(x)$ if and only if the polynomial $x-a$ [divides](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division) $f(x)$. So if you divide $h(x)$ by $x+2$ you get a polynomial of degree $2$. Do you know how to find the roots of a polynomial of degree $2$?

Comment: No I do not know how

Comment: @user160196, then you should definitely first understand [quadratic equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation).

Answer (score 0):

Okay, the first thing to do is polynomial division (or synthetic division, whichever you prefer).

Since -2 is a 0, we know that $(x+2)$ is a factor of $h(x)$. We then divide $h(x)$ by $(x+2)$

Dividing: $$\frac{x^3 + 8x^2 + 14x + 4}{x+2} = x^2 + 6x + 2$$

So $h(x)$ becomes: $$(x+2)*(x^2+6x+2)$$

Now you must use the Quadratic formula to find the root of $x^2 + 6x +2$

$$x = \frac{-6 +/- \sqrt{28}}{2}$$
$$x = -3 +/- \sqrt{7}$$

So $h(x)$ is $$(x+3+\sqrt{7})(x+3-\sqrt{7})(x+2)$$

Comment: Where did the x^2+6x+2 come from?

Comment: It came after dividing the two polynomials.

Comment: @user160196: You can get it using synthetic division, as you learned in your first two questions.

Comment: Ok thank you to the both of you for the help